# Does FaceBook.com have a sitemap?

Tags: facebook, sitemap

I'm working on a project and trying to figure out if FaceBook has a sitemap file.

Based off the research I've done, it looks like they used to have one at http://www.facebook.com/sitemap.php but that's not loading for me.

Does anyone know where it would be located at now?

Comment: This question is inappropriate for this site. try one of the other sites on stack exchange

Comment: What do you need it for?